# How to make user friendly column headings

Tags: php, mysql

I am looping through a wordpress database table, it outputs all table columns and data based on a chosen `ID`. It works as expected, but the downside is that it shows a not-so-user-friendly column heading on the front end. I'd like to change the table column headings to something more user friendly.

I had looked at using Alias with the query but I can't figure out a way to make that work with variables. Another thought was to make a separate table that had the same column names with 1 row of data holding the more user friendly column names and try to swap them out when creating the html.

But I'm not sure how i would get it to work inside the loop. Would that work, or is there a better way to make more user friendly column headings? As the amount of columns will grow in future, I can't hard code the column names in php, here's what I have so far:

```
$myquery = $mydb->get_results($mydb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$mydb->prefix}`mytable` WHERE id=%d", $myChosenID));

$output = "<div>";
    foreach($myquery as $key => $var) {
        if($key==0) {

            foreach($var as $col => $val) {
                $output .= '<div>';
                $output .= "<div>" . $col . '</div>';
                $output .= '<div><input name="' . $col . '" type="text" value="' . $val . '"></div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
            }
        }
        else {
            // output different html
        }
    }
    $output .= '</div>'; 
    echo $output;
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: If using the "separate table" mapping solution, look into "JOIN" to make the select in one query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked best for me was using a different table with the same col names and a row containing the new names, then fetching the new names in the for each loop.

```
$my_table = $mydb->prefix . '`my-table`';
$myquery = $mydb->get_results($mydb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$my_table} WHERE id=%d", $myChosenID));

$output = "<div>";
    foreach($myquery as $key => $var) {
        if($key==0) {

            foreach($var as $col => $val) {
                $table_name = $mydb->prefix . '`table-headers`';
                $field_name = $col;
                $getNewNames = $mydb->get_var($mydb->prepare( "SELECT {$field_name} FROM {$table_name} WHERE id=%d", 0));
                $output .= '<div>';
                $output .= "<div>" . $getNewNames . '</div>';
                $output .= '<div><input name="' . $col . '" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $val ). '"></div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
            }
        }
        else {
            // output different html
        }
    }
    $output .= '</div>'; 
    echo $output;
```